# Pdf upon transformation of multivariate random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, change-of-variable

What is the multivariate analogue to point 3. in this theorem? is || in here referring to absolute value?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You might want to read something related to "change of variables" and "Jacobian" such as [this](http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~moulib/426-notes-3.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is a one-to-one function on the support of $X$, then the pdf of $Y = g(X)$ is 
$$ f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) |\det(J(g^{-1}(y)))|$$
for $y$ in the range of $g$, where $J(x)$ is the Jacobian matrix of $g$ at $x$.

Yes, $| \cdot |$ means absolute value.

Comment: is it jacobian of $g$ or $g^{-1}$?

Comment: am guessing its for the inverse.

Comment: It should be the Jacobian of $g$.  If $g(x) = y$, the Jacobian of $g$ is defined at $x = g^{-1}(y)$.  The Jacobian of $g^{-1}$ at $x$ would make no sense, as $g^{-1}$ might not even be defined at $x$.